# Agregar estilos con js en el DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando agregar css a todos los elementos con la class menu-icon y menu-title, pero al hacerlo con js, sólo me añade el css al primer elemento. Es decir, tengo unos 10 elementos con esa etiqueta pero sólo añade el estilo al primero

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-title")[0];
x.style.marginLeft = "25px";

var y = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-icon")[0];
y.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
```

Comment: Y el `[0]` del final de la primera línea no te dice nada?

Comment: La verdad que si, me imagino que sea eso, pero nunca he usado getElementByClassName, siempre he usado ById

Comment: Tefef, la diferencia es que ID es unico y solo devuelve 1 resultado. El propio nombre de la funcion `getElementsByClassName` indica pluralidad. y poniendo `[0]` solo accedes al primer elemento..

Comment: get Element**s** by Class Name devuelve una lista, sólo tienes que recorrerla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claro, te lo añade al primer elemento porque le tienes puesto un `[0]`.

Al usar `getElementsByClassName`, te recoge una `lista` de elementos con esa misma clase. No es como `getElementById` porque un `id` es único.

Lo que tendrías que hacer sería recorrerlo, y por cada vuelta, le añades los estilos.

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-title");
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
     x[i].style.marginLeft = "25px";
}

var y = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-icon");
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
     y[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";    
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-title">Clase menu-title</div>
<div class="menu-title">Clase menu-title</div>
<div class="menu-title">Clase menu-title</div>
<div class="menu-icon">Clase menu-icon</div>
<div class="menu-icon">Clase menu-icon</div>
<div class="menu-icon">Clase menu-icon</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Como te indican, `getElementsByClassName` devuelve una lista de elementos con la clase indicada. Simplemente recórrela con un `for` y ya está.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-title");

for(elt of x){
  elt.style.marginLeft = "25px";
}

var y = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-icon");
for(elt of y){
  elt.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="menu-title">Menu 1</div>
<div class="menu-title">Menu 2</div>
<div class="menu-title">Menu 3</div>
<div class="menu-title">Menu 4</div>

<div class="menu-icon">Icono 1</div>
<div class="menu-icon">Icono 2</div>
<div class="menu-icon">Icono 3</div>
<div class="menu-icon">Icono 4</div>
</body>
</html>
```